# Connecting Python to FileMaker through pyodbc. Getting architecture mismatch error. Any advice?

Tags: python, pyodbc, filemaker, dsn

I'm trying to write a python program that connects to FileMaker through an odbc connection. I'm having trouble with errors that say there is an architecture mismatch. The FileMaker database I'm using is 64-bit, the DSN I set up uses a 64-bit driver, the python IDE I'm using (Jetbrains PyCharm) is 64-bit, **BUT** the shell is still running as 32-bit. Any ideas why? Or how I can force it to run as 64-bit?

I'm pretty new at Python, so sorry if I worded something wrong!

The following code is the beginning of my python script where the error occurs:

`import pyodbc 
connectString = "DSN=PYFM;UID='CONFIDENTIAL';PWD='CONFIDENTIAL'"
connection = pyodbc.connect(connectString)
cursor = connection.cursor()`

Comment: I assume this is on Windows. Is your Python also a 64-bit (amd64) build as opposed to a 32-bit one? You can tell by the banner the Python shell shows.

Comment: @AKX Yes it's on Windows, and yes my python is a 64-bit build

Comment: Have you set the Interpreter in PyCharm to be that 64-bit one?

Comment: @AKX How do I do that? I only saw one option for a 32-bit interpreter

Comment: In the preferences > project interpreter view, next to the interpreter drop down there's a button to add an interpreter.

Comment: I seem to recall that if you went to python.org and chose the default "install" option for Windows you'd get 32-bit Python. If you need 64-bit Python you can go back to the downloads page and select it specifically.